# How can I get session variable that is set in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to get a session variable that was set in flask but it doesn't work.

**This is the server side:**

```
session["user_request"] = search_request
print (session["user_request"])
```

**This is the client side:**

```
var user_request = '<%=Session["user_request"]%>';
alert(user_request);
```

I expect it to print the data given to it but it prints:    `<%=Session["user_request"]%>`

Comment: wrap it this way `{{Session["user_request"] }}`

Comment: var user_request = "<%= Session["user_request"]%>"; try with this one

Answer (score 0):

Python Code:-

```
session['data'] = 'data'
```

JS Code

```
var data = {{ session['data'] }}
console.log(data)
```

^^ (Case sensitive and spaces are mandatory)

Comment: It prints out undefined and when I refresh the page it says:" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & "

Comment: maybe there is a problem with the order? first I send a post request on the client side then I handle the post request and save the variable in the session in the server end and then as the callback function to the post request on the client side I try to get the variable